# Is there any way to find out what these custom attributes do in the google iosched app?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-theme, material-design

I've been looking to the Google iosched 2014 app to ensure im following correct design patterns for material design and specifically for pre-L devices with the support v7 library and appcompat v21.

In order to use the material design theme you must inherit from "Theme.AppCompat", but i can't seem to understand or find any documentation of the styles attributes in the link below. They aren't under the "android:" namespace and i dont seem to be able to use them myself.

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml#L32-L38

```
<item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
<item name="actionBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2</item>
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_up</item>
<item name="spinnerBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2_minus_16dp</item>
<item name="popupItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="photoItemForeground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="photoItemForegroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item
```

I'm barely familiar with custom attributes in /attr folder, but how can i find where they are used.

```
<declare-styleable name="BaseTheme">
    <attr name="actionBarIconColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="actionBarInsetStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="spinnerBarInsetStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="popupItemBackground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="photoItemForeground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="photoItemForegroundBorderless" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I don't understand how this custom set of attributes is being used and its bugging me. Can anyone explain to me whats going on here and how they attributes are being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a search of the repository that shows some instances of where they are used:

https://github.com/google/iosched/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=photoItemForeground

Comment: Thanks for that, this has definitely helped me understand whats going on. Basically i needed to brush up on my knowledge on themes and the use of the ? to reference a resource in the current theme. i had no idea you could search the repo like that :/